# Como faço meu app usar o "Galeria" padrão para pegar o caminho de uma imagem?

Tags: android

Já vi alguns aplicativos quem usa a Galeria padrão do Android para pegar imagens de uma determinada pasta, como faço isso?

É possível algum Android vir sem o aplicativo de Galeria? Ou a pessoa remover?

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo ao contrário:

> É possível algum Android vir sem o aplicativo de Galeria? Ou a pessoa remover?

Sim, é. Em custom rom é possível remover e no Android padrão, desde API 14 ou 15, não lembro exatamente, pode-se ir em Settings, Apps e desativar um aplicativo. Não remove do telefone, mas é o mesmo efeito, o aplicativo fica totalmente indisponível.

> Já vi alguns aplicativos quem usa a Galeria padrão do Android para pegar imagens de uma determinada pasta, como faço isso?

Lance um intent com a action ACTION_GET_CONTENT e trate o retorno no onActivityResult:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN = 1;

public void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    // Only the system receives the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, so no need to test.
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri fullPhotoUri = data.getData();
        // Do work with full size photo saved at fullPhotoUri
        ...
    }
}
```

O código acima veio da própria documentação do Android.